# How to load JWT token on to React during initial download after authentication from Multi Page Application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I have created a mix of Multi Page Application and Single Page Application which require authentication. The app stack is as follows.

- Node and Express for backend and multi page application
- React, React Router and Redux for single page application
- JWT token for authorization.

I have a none React login page that verifies email and passwords, generates the JWT token and redirects to the React app.

I want to save that token into the react app when the react app is first load in the client side. But I do not know how to do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):**

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a Storage
>   object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across
>   browser sessions. `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except
>   that while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data
>   stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends —
>   that is, when the page is closed.

---

### Basic worflow

When a user logs in, you will want to save the token on the clients local storage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('token', '2132434knfaskjdafnalenjgralejvnafjvk');
```

Then, when the user reloads the page, you will want to fetch it from localStorage:

```
const jwt = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
```

And finally, when the user logs out, we will remove the JWT from the users storage:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

Comment: But how do you set:
`window.localStorage.setItem('token', '2132434knfaskjdafnalenjgralejvnafjvk');`
When you are downloading the react app the same time.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You don't, you set it when a user has logged in. A user visiting your site is not a user logging in. Typically, that involves a login form

Comment: is it ok to set the header. (This is an express app.)
`res.set('token', '2132434knfaskjdafnalenjgralejvnafjvk')` 
then get this from react app.

Comment: @InfiniteDev you would set the header after the first and second example in my answer. So once a user is logged in, and you've saved the token, set the token on the header of the request

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am still very confused. My app shows a login page (not react) then my node app checks for authentication if passed it should redirect the user to the react app from which they can talk with my secure API using token. I do not understand where should I put `window.localStorage.setItem('token', '21324...');` Shouldn't this be at the same time the react app loads, if yes how is this possible. 
The answer I thought was to send the react app and the token in the response header to the client. React app will then save the token from the header to localStorage.

Comment: Ahhh, I see where the mixup is. If you have the JWT in the response header, then all you have to do is save it (when the user is redirected back to your app, of course) into local storage. Then, whenever a user enters your site (very first load), in javascript, check if the token exists in localStorage, if it does, re-add it to your request-headers.

Comment: You are very smart. Thank you

Comment: @InfiniteDev please mark this as accepted (the little checkmark by the upvote/downvote arrows)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store jwt in a secure and http only cookie. This is much safer than localstorage. In this way you can save your application from XSS attack. And if you have ssl in place then jwt hijacking will be difficult.

Saving jwt in localstorage makes it available for XSS attacks. Just set cookie in the response in the backend.

For Example:

```
res.cookie('jwt-token' , {'httpOnly': true , path:'path' , secure: true , maxAge: someNumber})
```

Comment: Saving it to a cookie makes it vulnerable to XSS as well, and if its not available to javascript, where exactly do you expect the front end to pull it from?

Comment: The browser will send cookie in each request to the server. The cookie will have jwt.

Comment: That doesn't answer my original question, the problem still stands.